# How to close and instance of repl.start() in node cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline, read-eval-print-loop

How do you close an instance of repl in a node cli module so it can run it twice without duplicating users input?

```
// Start repl instance and prompt user
var repl = require("repl");
let replServer = repl.start();
```

If I run this module twice when the user types 'a' the cli shows 'aa'

Using readline I used rl.close() to prevent duplicate input:

```
// Start readline instance
var rl= readline.createInterface({
   input: process.stdin,
   output: process.stdout
});

// Prompt user for input
rl.prompt();

// Close readline
rl.close()  // this prevents input being duplicated if I run module twice
```

Answer (score 0):

To close repl:

```
replServer.close()
```

The problem I was having with this, is that it closed out of the node app even though I called a module containing a readline.prompt().

To managed to get it working by calling the next module via 'on exit' rather than directly.

```
replServer.on('exit', () => {
  anotherModule()
}
```